# MDX - How to know if a measure has been pivoted with a dimension?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, ssas, ssas-2012

I was hoping someone could help me with this problem.
In a sum type measure, i need to know if this measure has been pivoted with my time dimension. If is not, the measure must show the sum of the last day. In other case, the measure must show the sum of the day with  has been pivoted.

I have the measure "Users", if this measure  hasn't  been pivoted with my time dimensión, it shows the sum of all users of all the time. For example it shows: 5,000,000. When it has pivoted with the time dimension, it shows de users from the day. For example: 100,000 for today 21/05/2015.

When this measure hasn't been pivoted with the "time" dimension, the measure must show 100,000 and not the total sum of all days.

I've been trying white some MDX formulas but i have not found some solution for this.

Thanks

Comment: I'm pretty sure what you want is not possible, nor should it be.

Answer (score 0):

I've interpreted this as when pulling your `Users` measure without pivoting on the `Time` dimension you would prefer to see the value that corresponds to the current date.

This can be achieved by modifying the `Default Member` of your `Time` dimension. [Setting the default date to this last available date](https://dwbi1.wordpress.com/2014/08/10/setting-the-default-date-to-last-available-date/)

- Within your **Dimension** in SSAS, browse to the **Dimension Structure** tab and select the attribute which represents the key column (ie. the Usage property is set to Key for only one column)
- Within the **Properties** pane (strike F4 if you do not see it already to open it) select the `Default Member` property, then select the elipses (...)
- The **Set Default Member - [Dimension Name]** pane will have 3 options, select the last **Enter an MDC expression that specifies the default member**
- Use ONE of the following expressions

  ```
  TAIL([Date].[DateAttribute].Members).Item(0)
  TAIL(NONEMPTY([Date].[DateAttribute].Members)).Item(0)
  TAIL(EXCEPT([Date].[Date].Members,{[Date].[Date].[Unknown]}),1).Item(0)
  ```

In my case I used the last as I  only want to exclude my `UnknownMember` member

Now when you pull the measure down the value will be for the **last date** in your cube. This will affect other cubes built on this date dimension of course.